# Gutenberg Blocks: registering more than one block with `register_block_type_from_metadata()` throws errors in the console

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I'm practicing how to create Gutenberg blocks plugin. I use [@wordpress/create-block](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-create-block/) to create a blocks plugin.

**Edit**: I didn't use the wp-cli scaffold as I initially stated, what I meant to write is that I used @wordpress/create-block.

The scaffold is made to only have one block on it, so, if you want more than one block you have to modify the structure, which is not that hard, but, I want the blocks to use block.json to register blocks with `register_block_type_from_metadata()`, which I achieved, but the problem is that if I use this code (register_block_type_from_metadata **twice**) in the main plugin's PHP file:

```
function blocks_boilerplate_block_init() {
    register_block_type_from_metadata( __DIR__ . '/src/blocks/example');
    register_block_type_from_metadata( __DIR__ . '/src/blocks/example2');
}
add_action( 'init', 'blocks_boilerplate_block_init' );
```

To register the blocks, the blocks get registered and they work without problems, but the Chrome console shows two errors.

Block "create-block/boilerplate-example" is already registered.

Block "create-block/guten-block-example2" is already registered.

If I use `register_block_type_from_metadata()` **only once**, the error goes away.

Any ideas on how to make the errors disappear?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was, when you use `@wordpress/create-block` to create a plugin with a block in it, and then you use `npm start` to run everything, webpack compiles all the blocks JavaScript code into a single file, which is fine and actually is desired, that way you don't have to enqueue a bunch of files. The block.json file includes a line `"editorScript": "file:../build/index.js"` (or something similar) to enqueue the main compiled JS file, and if you have only one block, that line is ok in the block.json file, but when you modify the structure of the plugin to include more blocks and every block has its own block.json file, including the `editorScript` line, then the blocks are registered several times, one for every block.json file you have, so, as a temporary solution, I deleted the `editorScript` line from all `block.json` files except one, and the errors disappeared, I didn't like that solution because it breaks consistency, so, I placed the following code in the plugin main php file:

```
function qas_enqueue_blocks_scripts() {
    $asset_file = require plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . 'build/index.asset.php';
    wp_enqueue_script( 'qas-main', plugins_url( '/build/index.js', __FILE__ ), $asset_file['dependencies'], 1.0, false);
}
add_action( 'enqueue_block_editor_assets', 'qas_enqueue_blocks_scripts');
```

The code above enqueues the main `index.js` file to the block editor and gets the file dependencies from `/build/index.asset.php` which is automatically generated when you run the initial commands to create the plugin and initial block. Using that code, you don't need to use the `editorScript` line anywhere, so you can delete it from all block.json files.

Other way to solve this is to modify the webpack configuration to compile only the code for the specific block to the main JS file, and then keep using `editorScript` in every `block.json`, but I haven't tried that yet.

Answer (score 2):

After setting up your Gutenberg block project with [wp-cli scaffold](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/scaffold/block/) and adding the two new blocks, your project structure may be something like:

```
- myblockname
    > build
    > node_modules
    - src
        - blocks
             - example1
                  - index.js
                  - block.json
             > example2
        index.js
myblockname.php
```

One approach to have multiple blocks load without conflict while using `block.json` is to import each block via the main `src/index.js`, that `wp-cli` created eg:

**src/index.js:**

```
import './blocks/example1/';
import './blocks/example2/';
```

Each of your blocks, (*example1* and *example2*) should have a `index.js` and `block.json` file to define the block, eg:

**src/blocks/example1/index.js:**

```
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';
import metadata from './block.json';
const { title } = metadata;

registerBlockType(name, {
    title, // required
    edit(){...}
    save(){...}
});
```

Now when you build your project, each of the example blocks are compiled into the single `build/index.js` and related assets.

If you then use the original main PHP file created from `wp-cli` scaffold (eg. myblockname.php), it will load the expected single built *index.js, index.asset.php, index.css etc* and enable you to bundle many blocks into one.

I've used this approach for a few past Gutenberg projects started from `wp-cli` to bundle multiple blocks quickly. I also looked at how [WordPress Gutenberg](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/trunk/packages/block-library/src/index.js) loads the block library and found the recently updated [WordPress Block API Documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-metadata/) helpful to work this approach out.

**Note:**
There is a potential disadvantage to this method of bundling all your blocks into one javascript file - they are all loaded even if not used. In my project, my blocks were dependancies of each other (innerBlocks) so it was beneficial. File size and loading time could be a concern depending on how many blocks you bundle.

For many blocks, a better approach would be for each block to build its own asset file then bundle those assets via "editorScript" and "script" in `block.json` but still use the main `index.js` as the entry point.

*If you still see the error that the name is already registered, check that each "example" block has a unique **"name"** in `block.json`*

Comment: Note: Newer version of `wp-cli` does enable adding multiple blocks, see: https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/scaffold/block/#examples